# React-redux with immer A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path

Tags: reactjs, redux, immer.js

I am pretty new to react so might be something silly here. I am using immer to produce next state but when trying to initialize ops I am getting this error

```
function updateCondition(state,action) {
  
  const nextState = produce(state, draftState => {
    draftState.rules[action.ruleIndex].conditions[action.conditionIndex][0] = action.value;
    draftState.rules[action.ruleIndex].conditions[action.conditionIndex][0].ops = {
      displayName: -1, 
      type : "none"
    }

  });
  return nextState;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can't reproduce the issue.